# Session expired for tomcat server in Kubernetes with replication

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, tomcat9

we had set up Kubernetes on aks we have load balancer for tomcat service with 2 replicas but when we login our application using external IP  (load balancer) we are getting an error saying that" session is expired and please login again" can anyone help me out.

Below are the YML files

Tomcat deployment file

```
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: tomcat
  spec:
    replicas: 2
    selector:
      matchLabels:
         app: tomcat
    strategy: {}
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: tomcat
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: (customimage):latest
          imagePullPolicy: ""
          name: tomcat-container
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
```

Service File

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: tomcat
  spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    selector:
       app: tomcat
```

Comment: Where you storing session data? By default tomcat storing session data locally, so you can't switching between pods. https://www.waitingforcode.com/tomcat/session-storage-in-tomcat/read You need to share session storage between containers or use sticky session that allow to access same container any time (actually sticky session is a bad idea for dynamic containers)

Comment: We are using tomcat image from public registry and directly setting up in Kubernetes. Do we need to setup session replication for tomcat?

Comment: I didn't use tomcat inside a container, and there are many ways to create authentication in web applications. So I can't answer definitely in your case. But, yes, here is high probability that you need share session data between instances. And replication is not a right way, because of time lags. Try to store sessions inside database.